# calloc / malloc and read weird behavior?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, system-calls

I'm trying to keep a dynamically allocated array of strings that are read in using the read system call in c. Here is a small sample of what I am trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void processInput() {
    char ** array = (char **) calloc(20, sizeof(char*));
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    while(1) {
        printf("Type something: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        char* buffer;
        int readResult = read(0, buffer, 100);

        array[arrayIndex] = (char*)calloc(readResult, sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

However, this causes some strange issues:

```
    Type something: a
    Type something: Type something: a
    Type something: Type something: abcdefg
    Type something: Type something: Type something: Type something: Type something: Type something: Type something: Type something:
```

Is there any explanation for this? I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: `char* buffer; readResult = read(0, buffer, 100);` Using uninitialized variables--especially uninitialized pointers--can only end in tears.

Comment: You're not incrementing `arrayIndex`

Comment: Sorry, the example was somewhat sloppy. you are correct that I was not  incrementing the arrayIndex, but it wasn't important to the example. However, in practice you are 100% correct that the arrayIndex will need to be incremented. Otherwise it won't be storing anything but the last added item in index 0 :P.

Comment: why have you removed the code? Question is now unanswerable and will likely be closed...

Comment: I've rolled-back to a revision with the code.  Ryan: please do not vandalize your questions.  Once there are answers, you owe it to those who have answered to leave the question in the form relevant to the answers.  If you need to modify the question, by all means edit it, but leave the original material visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
char *buffer;
```

with:

```
char buffer[100];
```

The dimension is consistent with the argument to `read()`, but your string will not be null terminated by `read()`, so you may prefer to allocate 101 bytes instead and forcibly null terminate it.  You need to think about that extra byte when allocating the space.

Note that the space that is allocated is not used.

You should always error check memory allocations before using them.

Since you only allocate 20 pointers before the loop, the `while (1)` loop is dangerous and could allow you to trample well beyond the allocated space if the user inputs more than 20 lines of data.

(Note that if the user redirects input from a file, you won't be reading 20 lines; you'll be reading 2000 characters in 20 blocks of 100 characters, newlines and all, and then running into crash territory.)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your output it looks like its running through the loop for each char in the input.